Cannot iterate over const view
I have written the following code:
int main()
{
    const std::vector v {1,2,3};
    const auto squared=v|std::ranges::views::filter(
        [](auto i){
            return i%2==0;
        }) | std::ranges::views::transform(
            [](auto i){
                return i*i;
            }
        );
    for (const auto s:squared){
        std::cout << s<<std::endl;
    }
}

(see https://godbolt.org/z/3345s3Yv5).
However, it does not compile since the iteration apparently discards qualifiers. Sure enough, making squared non-const allows it to build successfully. In addition, removing the filter also fixes the issue.
I want to understand why this is the case:

why does it need to be non-const? I imagine begin is a non-const function, but why? I feel it should be permitted to look over the elements of the range so long as I do not edit them
why does removing the filter fix this? I don't understand how it is different to the transform


The const in the for loop is rather useless. All it does is telling the compiler that your loop will not modify the local variable s (which is a copy of the original value), whose life-time ends each iteration of the loop.

@Someprogrammerdude It also tells coworkers that it's not modified in the loop, which is clearly visible here but may not always be trivial.

Note that transform_view is not relevant to the question. Your code would still fail if you didn't apply a transform_view, so this question is just asking why it doesn't work for filter_view.

Filter views are not const iterable when the underlying view models forward_range.
From cppreference

In order to provide the amortized constant time complexity required by the range concept, this function caches the result within the filter_view object for use on subsequent calls.


Makes sense, thanks for responding!
